# How can my TComponent intercept the ESC key and handle it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In my `TComponent`, there is a point where I want to listen to key events and intercept the `ESC` key and handle it in my component, consume/"eat" the keystroke, so that for example the owner form won't handle it at that stage. Just like in `TDragObject` when you start do drag and cancel it by pressing `ESC`.

Problem is that `TDragObject` has `AllocateHWnd` that is notified by it's owner form with `CN_KEYDOWN`. But no one notifies my component.

Do I need to replace the form's `WindowProc` with my own? If yes, then how to do it correctly "by the book" so to speak?

---

Just to be 100% clear:

```
TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
```

---

I made a small test and it seems to work:

```
TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FOldWindowProc: TWndMethod;
    FParentForm: TCustomForm;
    procedure FormWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;    
end;

...

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  if not (AOwner is TWinControl) then
    raise Exception.Create('TMyComponent.Create: Owner must be a TWinControl');
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  // hook parent form
  FParentForm := GetParentForm(TWinControl(Owner));
  if Assigned(FParentForm) then
  begin
    FOldWindowProc := FParentForm.WindowProc;
    FParentForm.WindowProc := FormWindowProc;
  end;
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  // unhook parent form
  if Assigned(FParentForm) then
    FParentForm.WindowProc := FOldWindowProc;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.FormWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  FOldWindowProc(Message);
  if Message.Msg = CM_CHILDKEY then // CM_CHILDKEY -> CM_DIALOGKEY -> CM_DIALOGCHAR
  begin
    OutputDebugString('CM_CHILDKEY');
    if Message.WParam = VK_ESCAPE then
    begin
      Beep;
      // do my stuff...
      Message.Result := 1; // consume keystroke
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I'm wondering if this is the right/only approach.

Comment: Dragging involves a new modal loop. That's not an option for you. Hard to see how you can do this cleanly without cooperation from the host.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the OP said "like in TDragObject", it's just an example and I assume the OP just wants the ESC key, nothing more, nothing less. ESC is a Dialog key. I just don't have the 1 minute required to look up the code/API/windows message right now.

Comment: @Cosmin A drag operation's modal loop owns and pumps the queue. And so can get hold of key presses. But a component on a form doesn't have that luxury. How do you propose to get inside the app's message loop?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I was thinking of the `WM_GETDLGCODE` handler with the `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS`; Don't have time to test.

Comment: @Cosmin Surely the dialog manager does not have anything to do with a VCL form.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan of course it does, and it's blocking the keys used for dialog navigation. It's (for example) what a `TMemo` does in order to get the Tab, Return and Arrows keys. Grep the message in the VCL sources.

Comment: @Cosmin OK. Presumably the control would need to have input focus.

Comment: @Vlad Like I said, you'll need to hook the main message queue. Off the top of my head, not sure how to do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I actually got some results, but not 100% it's all super duper :)

Comment: If *" there is a point where I want to listen to key events*" implies only a specific duration, you don't have to replace the window procedure for the entire lifetime of the component. BTW there are other approaches, like installing a message hook (`SetWindowsHookEx`), or having your own message loop... Discussing about the *right* approach, I guess, would require knowing the exact scenario.

Comment: `CM_CHILDKEY` will fire for input messages delivered to VCL controls. But not to non-VCL controls. That's probably fine for you. The way you replace `WindowProc` is fine. Apart from the bit where you write `TWinControl(Owner)`. That's invalid.

Comment: Check if you get WM_CANCELMODE messages. That's the usual way that Windows tells you the Esc key (or other event that cancels a capture/drag) must end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way might be to create a `TApplicationEvents` object inside of your component, and then use its `OnMessage` event to peek at messages from the main thread message queue, such as keystrokes, before the rest of the VCL processes them.

Comment: Can components realistically do that? What if the app assigns OnMessage? Won't that be a conflict?

Comment: `TApplicationEvents` is designed as a multicasting class. Multiple instances receive the same events. IOW, when a single message arrives in the queue, all assigned `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` handlers get dibs at it, if everyone uses `TApplicationEvents`, that is. If someone uses `TApplication.OnMessage` directly then `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` can break, and vice versa, yes. It is not a perfect system, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: `OnMessage` events from multiple `TApplicationEvents` components will be fired in reverse order of when those components are created.

Comment: Do you think it's a better solution than hooking WindowProc like I did?

Comment: The alternative is to use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to create a thread-specific keyboard hook or getmessage/wndproc hook. That would be more isolated than trying to hook the VCL events.